# pandas.concat: Cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! Pandas Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I am trying to concatenate 100 dataframes that have 2 datetime indexes using the following code:

```
concat_df = pd.concat([df_dict[c] for c in df_dict], axis = 1)
```

But somewhere one of the dataframes (I assume it is one but it could be more) is causing the following exception to occur:

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Any ideas why?

Is it referring to the first index or the second index?

Comment: Out of curiosity does this work `concat_df = pd.concat(list(df_dict.values()), axis = 1)`?

Comment: No that gave the same error... thanks

Comment: This may be some limitation of `concat` and probably not a bug but something where you have to decide how the data should be merged/aligned

Comment: `data.unstack('k1').duplicated('k1').any()` try this one where `data` is a single data frame and `k1` is the index name

Comment: Don't answer your question in the question. Post the answer as an answer.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the right (efficient) answer.. but I will do so.. sorry.

Comment: I have the same error on different problem. It turned out that when creating dataset there was duplicate column name, thus MultiIndex got generated.

Comment: Please let us know in which format you want your output? what do you have in df_dict?

Answer (score 1):

I found it was referring to the first index my solution was: (thought not sure how efficient it is but the concat works afterwards)

```
dup_first_index_dates = np.where(np.array([np.sum(df_dict[c].index.duplicated()) for c in df_dict]) == 1)[0]
key = df_dict.keys()
for i in dup_first_index_dates :
    df_dict[key[i]] = df_dict[tickers[i]].reset_index().drop_duplicates('Level1').set_index(['Level1', 'Level2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

probably the following option `ignore_index=True` of `concat` helps.

not sure if this could be use like follows:

```
concat_df = pd.concat([df_dict[c] for c in df_dict], axis = 1,ignore_index=True)
```

to try!